# COUNTIFS issue, output is always zero

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-query, google-sheets-arrayformula, concatenate

I have no idea what I'm doing, considering there's plenty of topics on `COUNTIFS`. However, each solution I've tried, as well as my own solutions, which I shall list, end up in the same thing... ZERO. It counts several cells and ends up as a zero, and I have no idea why, please help.

Here is the document.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Q899bG5tGPz0cIWUQ3K4_vxwRnZbsFCg6o-YS8Rhj74/edit?usp=sharing

So far I've used:

```
=COUNTIFS(G:G,"A",G:G,"M",G:G,"TM")
```

---

```
=SUM(COUNTIFS(A:A,"Active",G:G,{"A","M","TM"}))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pick one you like:

```
="Staff Roster - "&COUNTIF(G:G, "A")+COUNTIF(G:G, "M")+COUNTIF(G:G, "TM")
```

```
="Staff Roster - "&ARRAYFORMULA(COUNTA(IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(G:G, "A|M|TM"))))
```

```
="Staff Roster - "&COUNTA(IFERROR(QUERY(G:G, "where G='A' or G='M' or G='TM'")))
```

```
="Staff Roster - "&ARRAYFORMULA(SUMPRODUCT(REGEXEXTRACT({B3, B6, B12}, "\d+")))
```

```
="Staff Roster - "&COUNTA(G3:G)
```

```
="Staff Roster - "&COUNTA(IFERROR(FILTER(G:G, G:G<>"Rank")))
```

```
="Staff Roster - "&ARRAYFORMULA(SUM(IF((G:G="A")+(G:G="M")+(G:G="TM"), 1, )))
```

---

```
="Active Staff Roster - "&COUNTA(IFERROR(FILTER(B:B, B:B="Active")))
```

```
="Active Staff Roster - "&COUNTIF(B:B, "Active")
```

Comment: Once again, you've given more than I could ask for. Thank you, with all those options, I've modified it even further for my needs, thanks for showing me how its done!